# symbian C++ downsizing libraries

Tags: audio, audio-recording, sampling, downsampling

I wish to record audio at 32 kHz on my Symbian device but it only supports 48 kHz. From searching the internet I believe the term for what I am trying to do is called downsizing. Is there a C++ library that will compile and run on Nokia Symbian phones that will do this for me? Or is the algorithm simple enough for me to implement on my own?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The term you are looking for is [downsampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Downsampling). You can probably get the code you need from the sources of the open source [SoX](http://sox.sourceforge.net/) utility.